# What does @SupportsBatching exactly do on top of NiFi's processor class?

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I have looked into NiFi's [Developer Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/developer-guide.html), [User Guide](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html) and [NiFi In-Depth](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html), but I was unable to find anything about `@SupportsBatching` annotation.

If I go to source of that annotation/interface, I read this JavaDoc:

> *Marker annotation a Processor implementation can use to indicate that users should be able to supply a Batch Duration for the Processor. If a Processor uses this annotation, it is allowing the Framework to batch ProcessSessions' commits, as well as allowing the Framework to return the same ProcessSession multiple times from subsequent calls to ProcessSessionFactory. createSession(). When this Annotation is used, it is important to note that calls to ProcessSession.commit() may not provide a guarantee that the data has been safely stored in NiFi's Content Repository or FlowFile Repository. Therefore, it is not appropriate, for instance, to use this annotation if the Processor will call ProcessSession.commit() to ensure data is persisted before deleting the data from a remote source. When the defaultDuration parameter is set, the processor is created with the supplied duration time, which can be adjusted afterwards. The supplied values can be selected from DefaultRunDuration.*

but this is definitely not clear to me.

My question is simple: **What does `@SupportsBatching` actually do**, in a simplest possible words, please?

In the course of the last month, I'm getting more and more into NiFi. I have to say, that documentation, community and support is quite lacking for this technology.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that the Scheduling Tab of the processor will show a Run Duration slider in the UI when the component is marked with this annotation.

Run Duration is like a batch time, meaning if you set it to 5 seconds it allows the NiFi framework to execute the processor for up to 5 seconds, and treat all of the executions during that time as a single batch which is more efficient in terms of updating internal repositories.

This allows you to make a trade-off between latency and throughput...

A run duration of 0 would basically mean no batching, so each flow file will move through the system independently as fast as possible, so low latency.

A higher run duration means an individual flow file may not be transferred from the processor until a batch is complete, which makes the flow file take longer to reach the end of the flow, but may lead to more overall flow files being processed in the same time period (higher throughput).

Additional information...
https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/user-guide.html#run-duration